# When to Use Width and Height Property in CSS?

Tags: html, css, web

This is the html:

```
<section class="section-meals">
        <ul class="meals-showcase">
            <li>
                <figure class="meal-photo">
                    <img src="resources/img/1.jpg">
                </figure>
            </li>
            <li>
                <figure class="meal-photo">
                    <img src="resources/img/2.jpg">
                </figure>
            </li>
            <li>
                <figure class="meal-photo">
                    <img src="resources/img/3.jpg">
                </figure>
            </li>
            <li>
                <figure class="meal-photo">
                    <img src="resources/img/4.jpg">
                </figure>
            </li>
        </ul>
</section>
```

Here is the css:

```
.section-meals {
    padding: 0;   
}

.meals-showcase {      /*This is a ul*/
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
}

.meals-showcase li {   /*This is a li element inside of a ul*/
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
}

.meal-photo {       /*This is a figure html element inside of a li*/
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #000;
}

.meal-photo img {     /*This is a img element inside of a figure element*/
    opacity: 0.7;
    width: 100%;
    transform: scale(1.15);
    transition: transform 0.5s, opacity 0.5s;
}

.meal-photo img:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1.03);

}
```

In the above css code I am a little confused when to set the width and height property in the css.

For example in `.meal-photo`, I set the width to 100% to make sure that the figure html element will have the exact same width of its parents which is `.meals-showcase li`. But for `.meal-photo img` is the height property automatically inherited from `.meal-photo` which is its parent. Since whether I set it or not the height doesn't change for the image.

Comment: Please provide a http://jsfiddle.net showing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortest answer is that you use the width and height when you want to explicitly specify those values. If not, default values are used, depending on the element.

With regard to DIVs, the default width is 100%. So if you don't mention the width, it extends end to end. But the height is not so. Also like you've correctly noticed, the 100% means, up to the width of its parent.

As for img tags, they take the default dimensions of the image. So if you even give a value like `width:150px` and leave `height:auto`, the height scales according to the proportion of the width.

But there are some other elements like the span tag. Its default width is the width of the contents.

In all of the cases, pay attention to the padding and margins of both the element being scaled and the parent object. They affect the appearance.

Comment: Ohhh, so are you saying that by default if you do not put a height on the image it will automatically scale "according to the proportion of the width as you mentioned"?

Comment: @ClayHorder you've answered your own question in the comment - smiles... If you just try it, you should see that since the width is 100%, the height is automatic (i.e., the current dimension). Experiment by making only the width to 50% and see what happens to the height.

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing this up! This has been bothering me for a long time... haha

Comment: Great answer, makes it easy to understand. Good job

Comment: @itsols Quick question. Then really the only time you would want to set the height of an image is if you want it to be a specific height correct? Otherwise you can just set the width of the image and the height will scale automatically with accordance to the width.

Comment: @ClayHorder Yes, your comment to clarify is correct. But also keep in mind that it's true the other way. That means, if you set the height, you can set width to auto-scale. So this means that either one can be set and the other can be auto. Like I said in the start, it comes down to what you want to do.

Comment: @itsols Sorry for the late reply! But that makes complete sense, thanks for all the help! Also one last question haha... When you set the width or height of an element is that width or height always with respect to the parent elements width or height? So for example say we have a div element that has a width of 100px and you have a img in there and you set the width for that img to be 25%. Will the width of the image be 25% of 100px which is the width of its parent container?

Answer (score 0):

To set the image width to 100% of the parent element you need to use

```
max-width: 100%
```

Same for height.

Comment: Hi, yes I realize that. But my questions is in the ".meal-photo img" css selector is the height for that img inherited from ".meal-photo" css selector? Since I never set the height in the ".meal-photo img" and whether I set it or not the image height remains the same. So is it being inherited from somewhere else?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot or something to describe what you mean with it is inherited from it's parent? The inner content will not be bigger than it's parent if you don't define it.

Comment: I think I got it now. As @itsols metioned by default the height of the image will automatically scale with accordance to the width you set regardless if you put a height property or not on the image.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how you want the responsiveness of your webpage to work. If you use

```
   width:100%;
```

then when you resize your browser to half of the screen crosswise, your width will be browser width will be cut down in half, making your width 25% of the original. Using height does the same but for height.

To set the width to 100% of the parent div, use

```
min-width:100%;
```

To make it responsive based on height, make sure to set a height for the parent div. You can use vh or vw to set measurements based on the height or width of your screen. Ex:

```
min-height:50vh;
```

Comment: Will keep this in mind. I am actually trying to create a responsive site. Thanks for the tip!